# How do you do RAM Purging in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, memory-management, ram, purge

I've never messed with memory before besides using Memory Streams. But I recently downloaded a RAM Cleaner that "purges" memory. I'm very curious on how it works and what it does. I tried googling some things about memory cleaning and purging but it's not making too much sense to me. How does memory cleaning work? Where can I learn more about it? Is it performing some sort of garbage collection on processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this API Function help you friend...This function was very useful for me because calling the EmptyWorkingSet/SetProcessWorkingSetSize is just a way to clean up before the OS does it.

I think This is C# syntax... Convert and try this in VB.net :

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

[DllImport("psapi.dll")]
public static extern bool EmptyWorkingSet(IntPtr hProcess);

    public void Clean()
    {
        // get handle to a process
        Process ThisProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

        // empty as much as possible of its working set
        bool Result = EmptyWorkingSet(ThisProcess.Handle);

    }
```

ThisProcess.Handle is the Process's Handle of your program.

and also look this : [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682606(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I've tried converting this over to VB.NET and I got most of it but there's a part that's not working. I placed the code into a console application. http://pastebin.com/M66htGaf

Comment: Never mind I got it working perfectly. So emptying working sets? Pretty cool. I think I get it now. It's releasing pages right?

Comment: I saw your VB code ... It seems to be true.as far as I got it...This way decreases both pages and memory usage...you can check this event by looking at TaskManager>Processes>Memory Column.I can Help you friend later If you can not how to use this code in VB.